# Transfer Funds using Payment Gateway API

Tags: payment-gateway

we are developing a solution for service providers to register and get paid for their services.

1. Members => Will request a service
2. Providers => Will complete the work and charge an invoice.
3. Members => Will pay the invoice.
4. System will credit the amount to the Service providers Bank AC/CC.

We are looking for a solution which can credit the service provider the amount thus paid on the website. We wish to avoid double charges since we do not intend to get the payment in our account, just transfer it between the two entities.

This is similar to paying your utility bills using a third party site.

Does any payment gateway or service provide such a service ? How do we go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal enables you to create and manage invoices by APIs. When you send an invoice, PayPal emails the recipient and allows him or her to pay with PayPal.
Read more about Invoicing [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/IntroInvoiceAPI/) and [Invoicing API Examples](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/InvoiceAPIExamples/).

Comment: Hi,Thank you. This is certainly helpful. This I believe requires the providers to have a PayPal account. Ideally, would want to be able to credit a bank account or CC of the providers. I know there will be issues around that.

Other option is to take credit ourselves, and then transfer to the providers's bank A/C with ACH or something, but I believe it will be more expensive.